# Not getting properties on generic parameter T when trying to create generic comparer to compare 2 objects

Tags: c#, .net, iequalitycomparer

I want to compare 2 objects like below :

- I don't want 2 employees in the same department
- I don't want 2 Animals in the same Zoo
- So on.....

I am trying to implement IEqualityComparer to accept generic type argument to take Employee or Animals or any object and to the comparison for me but I ran into a problem because since I have T as an argument, I am not getting the properties on T.

```
public class GenericComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
        // Not getting a property here T.??
            //now if I would have T as an Employee then I could do something like this here:
       // return String.Equals(x.Name, y.Name); // but this will work because I know that Name is string 
     // but lets say if I have a different datatype that I want to compare then how can i do that?
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return obj.
        }
    }
```

The thing is I don't want to create 2 classes like `EmployeeComparer: IEqualityComparer<Employee> and AnimalComparer : IEqualityComparer<Animal>` as the code will be somewhat similar.

Is it possible to create generic compared to compare any objects of the same types?

**Update:**

I am just trying to understand the limitations of generics with reference types. When should we create a Generic class or methods to accept reference types and when we should not.

I was thinking that since `List<T>` can accept anything like `List<Employee>` or `List<Animal>` or anything then why my GenericComparer cannot.

Because when we create `List<Employee>` then we can run for each loop and access the properties right:

```
foreach(var employee in employees)
{
  string name = employee.Name; //Here we are able to access the properties
}
```

Then how come not in my case?

Answer to all the above questions will help me understand generics better with reference type especially. So, if someone can provide an answer to all this question and why it is not possible with my `GenericComaprer<T>` and how it is possible with `List<T>` then I will really appreciate :)

Comment: You should consider setting a generic constraint on T, for example that in needs to be a base implementation of the type you are comparing. Then those common properties of the base implementation will appear. Since you dont want to create multiple classes you could check if x/y are a certain type then cast them to access their properties. I can't recommend the second approach :)

Comment: Not sure if it is helpful or not, But, you can access the properties using 'x.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(x, null);'and compare the values.

Comment: I would likely approach this by simply having your classes implement IEquatable<T>.

Comment: That is how generics work, they do not represent any particular type unless you put a constraint on the generic type (like `where T: IMyType`). But that is the main problem! You want to create a generic comparator. Okay, but compare what? If you say  - _not the same employee twice_, how do you know If 2 employees are same? Based on what? If you can define that in a generic way (e.g. `Guid Id` property), you can put that constraint on the generic type.

Comment: @ArghyaC I have a Name property in my employee class to compare but then if I will make it like IEqualityComparer<Employee> then I will have to create another class for IEqualityComparer<Animals> too and so on. I am trying to avoid that. There is no way to create a Generic Comparer ?

Comment: @olabacker Can you post any examples of either approach for better understanding please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when we create `List<Employee>` then we can run for each loop and access the properties

Sure, because you are *using* `List<T>` by providing it the concrete type (`Employee`) to use in place for `T`. But if you were to look at the internals of (or try to write your own version of) `List<T>` you'd see you have no way to access an hypothetical `Name` property of `T`. That is because C# is a strictly typed language (contrarily to Javascript or Python for example). It won't let you use anything it doesn't know beforehand and for sure exists.

The way you defined your `GenericComparer<T>` class, all the compiler know is that `T` can do what every C# objects can, that is... not much (you can use `ToString()` and `GetType()` and compare references, that's pretty much all).

Then, because otherwise generics wouldn't be very useful, you can specify **constraints** on your generic type: you can, for example, tell the compiler that `T` must implement some interface. If you do this, then you can access any member defined in this interface on your `T` instances from inside the generic class.

For the sake of the example, let's say you have employees and animals; both employees and animals have a `Name`, then employees also have a `Salary` but animals have a `Species`. This could look like this:

```
public class Employee {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
}

public class Animal {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Species { get; set; }
}
```

If we keep it that way, as explained above, you won't be able to access the properties from your generic class. So let's introduce an interface:

```
public interface IHasName {
    string Name { get; }
}
```

And add  `: IHasName` at the end of the `Employee` and `Animal` class declarations.

We also need to tweak `GenericComparer` declaration this way:

```
public class GenericComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : IHasName
```

By doing this, we tell the compiler that the `T` in `GenericComparer` must implement `IHasName`. The benefit is now you can access the `Name` property from within `GenericComparer`. On the other side, you won't be able to use `GenericComparer` by passing it anything that doesn't implement `IHasName`. Also note that the interface only defines the ability to *get* the `Name` property, not to *set* it. So, although you can of course set the `Name` on `Employee` and `Animal` instances, you won't be able to do so from inside `GenericComparer`.

With the definitions above, here is an example of how you could write the `GenericComparer<T>.Equals` method:

```
public bool Equals(T x, T y)
{
    // Just a convention: if any of x or y is null, let's say they are not equal
    if (x == null || y == null) return false;

    // Another convention: let's say an animal and an employee cannot be equal
    // even if they have the same name
    if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;

    // And now if 2 employees or animals have the same name, we'll say they are equal
    if (x.Name == y.Name) return true;

    return false;
}
```

All that said, I don't know exactly what your use case for `GenericComparer<T>` is (maybe you need this in a `Dictionary` or some other method that requires a way to compare instances... Anyway, as other commenters have stated, the proper way to go would probably be to:

- override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`
- provide `==` and `!=` operators
- implement `IEquatable<T>`
- Do this on all classes you want to have a custom implementation of equality.

If you happen to use a recent version of Visual Studio (I'm using VS 2019 16.8 at the moment), you can automatically do all of this by right-clicking the class name, choosing *Quick Actions and Refactorings* > *Generate Equals and GetHashCode*. You will be presented with a window that allows you to choose the properties that should be part of the equality logic and you can also optionally choose to implement `IEquatable<T>` and generate `==` and `!=`. Once done, I'd recommend you review the generated code and make sure you understand what it does.

By the way, if you do so, you'll notice that the generated code uses [`EqualityComparer<Employee>.Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1.default). This is pretty much what you tried to implement by yourself with your `GenericEqualityComparer`.

Now to the part of your questions relating to *reference* types. I'm not sure I understand your questions for I don't see an obvious link between generic types and references. Generic types can act just as well on both *reference* and *value* types.

What bothers you is maybe the fact that *equality* does not work the same way in reference and value types:

- For reference types, the default way the compiler considers things equal is to look at their references. If the references are the same, then the things are considered the same. To put it differently suppose you create 2 instances of an Employe **class** and feed them with exactly the same `Name` and `Salary`. Because they are distinct objects (with distinct places in memory, that is different references), `emp1 == emp2` will return `false`.
- In the case of value types (suppose `Employee` is a `struct` and not anymore a `class`), the compiler does something else: it compares all the properties of the `struct` and decides based upon their content whether the 2 employees are equal or not. In this case, `emp1 == emp2` will return `true`. Note that here, the compiler (or rather the .NET runtime) is doing something similar to what you attempt to do with your universal comparer. However, it only does so for *value* types and it is rather slow (this is why one should often implement `IEquatable` and override `Equals` and `GetHashcode` on structures).

Well, I'm not sure I've answered all your questions, but if you want to know more, you should definitely go through some C# tutorials or documentation to understand more about reference vs value types and equality (even before you jump into implementing your own generic types).

Comment: Upvoted for such a comprehensive answer and for your kind efforts towards helping me. I am trying to use it on  var dic = new SortedDictionary<string, HashSet<Employee>>();. I want to ensure I don't have same employees in 1 dept. Can you please show me how do I use it with Hashset?

Comment: I suppose the string key represents the department. Then, the same employee must appear only once per department, but they can belong to several departments. Am I right?

Comment: I have sent you an invite here and I have shared some code: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228377/room-for-ilovestackoverflow-and-odalet

Answer (score 1):

What you're expecting of generics just isn't right:

> I was thinking that since `List<T>` can accept anything like `List<Employee>` or `List<Animal>` or anything then why my GenericComparer cannot.
>
> ```cs
> foreach(var employee in employees)  
> {
>   string name = employee.Name; //Here we are able to access the properties
> }
> ```

Here you say that you can access the properties, but that's specifically because the list `employees` was instantiated as `List<Employee>`. The implementation of `List` however could Not access those properties, because it only sees `T` !

---

There are some ways to achieve what you want, but you'd have to consider design and performance pros/cons depending on your specific use-case and needs.

Here's what you could do:

```cs
public abstract class CustomComparable
{
    // Force implementation to provide a comparison value
    public abstract object GetComparisonValue();
}

public class Employee: CustomComparable
{
    public int Department { get; set; }

    public override object GetComparisonValue()
    {
        return Department;
    }
}

public class Animal : CustomComparable
{
    public string Zoo { get; set; }

    public override object GetComparisonValue()
    {
        return Zoo;
    }
}

public class CustomComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T: CustomComparable
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return x != null && y != null && x.GetComparisonValue().Equals(y.GetComparisonValue());
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return obj.GetComparisonValue().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you'd get this, for example:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal cat = new Animal() { Zoo = "cat zoo" };
        Animal dog = new Animal() { Zoo = "dog zoo" };
        Animal puppy = new Animal() { Zoo = "dog zoo" };
        List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>() { cat, dog, puppy };
        CustomComparer<Animal> animalComparer = new CustomComparer<Animal>();

        Console.WriteLine($"Distinct zoos ? {animals.Distinct(animalComparer).Count() == animals.Count}");

        Employee bob = new Employee() { Department = 1 };
        Employee janet = new Employee() { Department = 2 };
        Employee paul = new Employee() { Department = 3 };
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>() { bob, janet, paul };
        CustomComparer<Employee> employeeComparer = new CustomComparer<Employee>();

        Console.WriteLine($"Distinct departments ? {employees.Distinct(employeeComparer).Count() == employees.Count}");
    }
}

> Distinct zoos ? False
> Distinct departments ? True
```

---

With all that being said, do use `IEquatable<T>`. The specific use of such equality implementations seems out of the scope of your initial question however, and many other resources and Q&A's can help you with these.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but don't you think CustomCaparable as an interface makes more sense as it represents behaviour. Just a thought :)

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow oh yes absolutely; @odalet had already brought up the interface solution, so I just showed one with `abstract` (hence the "you'd have to consider design and performance pros/cons" notice). FWIW though, I do think these points are moot since `IEqualityComparer` clearly doesn't seem to be what you ultimately need. ^^

Comment: Then best would be to use IEquatable? If yes then why IEquatable?

Comment: Because it forces you to have a generic use `IEquatable<T>` for comparison of objects you Know have their own `Equals` function.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is easily possible, just use delegates.

```
public class GenericComparer<T, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private Func<T, TValue> _getter;
    private IEqualityComparer<TValue> _valueComparer;

    public GenericComparer(Func<T, TValue> getter, IEqualityComparer<TValue> valueComparer = null)
    {
        _getter = getter;
        _valueComparer = valueComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _valueComparer.Equals(_getter(x), _getter(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return _valueComparer.GetHashCode(_getter(obj));
    }
}
```

To use it, simply tell it by which property you want it to compare:

```
var animalByNameComparer = new GenericComparer<Animal, string>(an => an?.Name);
```

Of course, you can also handle the null case already in the generic comparer, also.

**To your second question**
The simple difference between `List<T>` and `List<Employee>` is that the former is an open generic type while the latter is a closed generic type. If you define a generic type, you always define it as an open generic type, so the compiler does not know what `T` will be. If you consume a generic type, you often work with closed generic types, i.e. the placeholder `T` already has a value and therefore, the compiler is able to resolve a symbolic name like `.Name` to a property. If you use the generic type in an open generic method (a method with a type parameter), you also cannot bind symbols.

Comment: Wow, very nice and upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me. I am just trying to understand that whats the use case when we create a generic class to accept reference types ie class and couldn't figure it out. Can you tell me any use case when do we have generic class of T to accept only reference types because as a lot of people mention that we don't have access to class properties then what can you do inside the class when we have T as reference type?

Comment: If `T` is a reference type, this allows you to do safe casts using `as`, though this advantage has almost vanished since we have pattern matching. The only other reason I can think of is that delegate binding sometimes fails for value types.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. Actually I would like to know what Pattern Matching and Delegate Binding you are talking about. Any reference you can share for me to read up?